# Is it possible to setup VPN through anydesk TCP Tunneling?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, tunnel

I noticed that AnyDesk also provide TCP tunneling option, and I was wondering, can I use this in order to connect VPN to other LAN? If so, how?

Comment: Do you want a full VPN or just to access some specific hosts or services on the remote network?

Comment: @golimar just to specific host using AnyDesk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a real VPN, but if you just need to connect to specific hosts on the remote network you can use AnyDesk 5.1 or newer (both on local and remote PCs), once connected go to Setup TCP Tunneling and create one like this:

Local host: 8881 , Remote host: 10.0.0.55, Remote port: 8881

After that, you can reach from your local PC to the remote host 10.0.0.55:8881 by connecting to localhost:8881 on the local PC

More info: https://support.anydesk.com/TCP-Tunneling

Comment: not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Super User I don't know about AnyDesk, but most VPNs tunnel to the same network: the internet. You can set up tunneling between two LANs, if you control a computer on both LANs.

But instead, what most people do is to control a computer on the remote LAN directly — and do their web browsing, etc from that remote computer — instead of taking their local web browsing, etc and sending it over to the remote LAN.

This is often called "remoting in," to the remote computer, or "remote desktop." There are products like TeamViewer and SSH which do this. (And, SSH also can do a proper VPN with something called a SOCKS proxy, although it requires the remote server to be accessible to the internet.)

The difference between remote desktop and VPN is that a remote desktop session exists in a single window. Whatever you do in that window happens on the remote computer, and therefore happens on the remote LAN. With a VPN (typically), whatever you do in any app goes over the VPN, and it behaves as if your local computer exists on the remote LAN.

From what I can see, [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en) advertises itself as a remote desktop app, so yes, it does give you access to a remote network (indirectly) by allowing you to control a computer on that network. But, no, it probably does not actually VPN the network traffic from your local computer to originate from the remote network, the way that a VPN redirects your local traffic to originate from, say, Russia.

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying to the question for someone who is still interested. Anydesk added the VPN to the list of features available for Linux and macOS devices.

You can find the VPN feature in the list of actions (the thunderbolt icon) in the Anydesk user bar. Once enabled, Anydesk will create a VPN tunnel between the local machine and the remote machine.
Then you can do whatever you want (such as SSH-ing into the remote one) using the remote IP listed in the Anydesk window.

You can find the Anydesk documentation page [here](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/vpn)